# Error while saving PySpark Model to Blob storage

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

This is the code I am using to save my Pyspark model to Azure blob storage. I am able to connect to the blob and see the existing files inside it from Spark.
  model.write().overwrite().save("wasbs://containername@blobname.blob.core.windows.net/model.model")

```
Caused by: shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureException: Uploads to to public accounts using anonymous access is prohibited.
    at shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureNativeFileSystemStore.storeEmptyFolder(AzureNativeFileSystemStore.java:1587)
    at shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem.mkdirs(NativeAzureFileSystem.java:2692)
    at shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem.create(NativeAzureFileSystem.java:1754)
    at shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem.create(NativeAzureFileSystem.java:1561)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:911)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:804)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(TextOutputFormat.java:123)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapRedWriteConfigUtil.initWriter(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:230)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.org$apache$spark$internal$io$SparkHadoopWriter$$executeTask(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$$anonfun$3.apply(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$$anonfun$3.apply(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.doRunTask(Task.scala:140)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:113)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$13.apply(Executor.scala:537)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1541)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:543)
```

Comment: please provide a full error stack trace

Comment: Are you using SAS token or credentials to login and perform actions against blob storage?

Comment: I tried access key and SAS token. Also, I was able to write a Spark Dataframe as CSV to blob but the CSV file in blob is empty. It didn't throw the above-mentioned error though.

Answer (score 0):

**Set up the Blob storage account access key in the notebook session conf by adding the below code above your code : -**

```
spark.conf.set(
  "fs.azure.account.key.<your-storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net",
  "<your-storage-account-access-key>")
```

Comment: @jeffinjacob Did you get chance to check this